# How do I use sqlsrv_next_result() to retrieve multiple records?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have this table named `tblDate` which contains the columns `dateID`, `dateDay`, and `dateMonth` along with 30 records for the month of November. Using `sqlsrv_fetch_array()`, I can only retrieve the first record. I have read [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-next-result.php) that in order to retrieve the multiple records, I need to use `sqlsrv_next_result()`, but how exactly do I use it? As I understand it, this function makes the next record "active," which would then allow me to echo the next record and so on. But when I try to run this code:

```
$tsql = " SELECT * FROM tblDate;";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);

$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
echo "Date: ".$row["dateID"]." - ".$row["dateMonth"]." ".$row["dateDay"]."\n";

$next_row = sqlsrv_next_result($stmt);

$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
echo "Date: ".$row["dateID"]." - ".$row["dateMonth"]." ".$row["dateDay"]."\n";
```

I get the error:

> Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in ...

I get that `sqlsrv_next_result($stmt)` returns the boolean false when there are no further records, but there are more records. I expected this code should fetch me the first two records, did I misunderstand something? Also, I don't get "consume the first result"; how does that and insert records come into play?  I've tried just straight up copy-pasting and replacing the variables but I cant seem to get it to work.  Though honestly, this is my very first week working with php so I have no idea what I'm doing. Ultimately, I just want to display all records of a query[`SELECT * FROM tblDate` among others], how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this (untested!):

```
while (($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH, SQLSRV_SCROLL_NEXT)) !== NULL)
{
    // Your business logic using $row.
}
```